# SQL GROUP BY with two tables involved

Tags: mysql, sql, database-table

Could you guys help me to make SELECT query for my simple case:

```
Table A:        
UserID  UserName
10      John
11      Mike
12      Matt


Table B:            
SessionID   UserID  SessionTime
124         10      20
123         10      122
42          10      30
324         11      55
534         11      42
344         12      19
653         12      32
```

I need this result:

```
Result Table:               
UserName    UserID  TotalTime
John        10      172
Mike        11      97
Matt        12      51
```

For one Table B this works:

```
SELECT UserID, SUM(SessionTime) AS "Total Time"
FROM TableB
GROUP BY UserID;
```

but I need to attach UserName to the final result

thank you

Comment: This is a simple `JOIN` + `GROUP BY`. What challenges did you face in the SQL build?

Comment: sorry for that simple question, the main challenge probably is late night in Europe zone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using join and group by:

```
select a.UserId, a.UserName, sum(b.SessionTime) as TotalTime
from tableA a
left join tableB b on a.UserId = b.UserId
group by a.UserId, a.UserName;
```

Note: This would work for 1-to-many relations as in your case.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TableA.Username, TableA.User_ID, SUM(SessionTime) INNER JOIN
TableB ON TableA.User_ID = TableB.User_ID GROUP BY TableA.Username,
TableA.User_ID
```

Comment: Sorry, TableA.User_ID should be TableA.UserID to match your example fully.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.UserName as "UserName" 
      ,a.UserID as "UserID"
      ,sum(b.SessionTime) as "TotalTime" 
FROM a LEFT JOIN b 
ON a.UserID = b.UserID GROUP BY a.UserID
```

Here. I used TABLE a and Table b

Comment: There is no difference of the acccepted answer, besides you forgot a.username in groupby so it will not work